# Ubuntu Server Issue: Can't Install Packages | Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend

Tags: apt, dpkg

I'm using a Ubuntu 22.04 server with Docker containers for smart devices. Lately, I can't install anything because I keep getting a lock-frontend error.

I looked for what's causing the problem but found nothing. I restarted the server, but the problem didn't go away. Whenever I try to install or upgrade something, the same error comes up.

I even tried removing the lock file, but it didn't help. It seems like the system is stuck waiting for itself, and I'm not sure how to fix it.

If I am to kill the first result it simply kills my running dpkg action

The error message:

```
Waiting for cache lock: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend. It is held by process 3003989 (apt)
```

`sudo dpkg --configure -a` does not help either, has the same issues as apt.

Listing running processes for pid results in:

```
ps aux | grep 3003989
root      3003989  0.1  0.0  13492  7528 pts/1    S+   14:17   0:00 dpkg --configure -a
root      198985  0.0  0.0   6608  2432 pts/4    S+   14:17   0:00 grep --color=auto 3003989
```

I don't want to reinstall everything. If anyone can help, that would be great. I haven't found anyone else with this problem. Thanks for any help you can give.

Answer (score 1):

The message says  `/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend` is held by the process `3003989`. So apparently you can **KILL** the process to fix the issue(most likely)

But before proceeding to kill, check if the PID(In this case, `3003989`) is that of any process that might result in damage or data loss of any kind.

Use any of the following commands to find the process:

```
ps -p <PID>
ps aux | grep <PID>
```

In your example the PID is `3003989` so `ps -p 3003989` or `ps aux | grep 3003989`

It will list the process, if the process is not related, you may try killing it.

For **KILLING** the process:

```
sudo kill <PID>
```

If that doesn't kill it;

```
sudo kill -9 <PID>
```

***PROCEED AT YOUR OWN RISK***

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I did try this, just through HTOP initially. I added an example to my original posting, killing the processes listed does not help, and simply kills my dpkg action.